# Angular VS Code не подключаются скрипты js

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-code

Всем привет! Пытаюсь запустить простейший пример AngularJS в VS Code.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Aexam1</title>
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="phoneController">
        <p>Название: {{phone.name}}</p>
        <p>Цена: {{phone.price}} $</p>
        <p>Производитель: {{phone.company.name}}</p>
    </div>
    <script src="/src/app/js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
        myApp.controller('phoneController', function($scope) {

            $scope.phone = {

                name: 'Nokia Lumia 630',
                year: 2014,
                price: 200,
                company: {
                    name: 'Nokia',
                    country: 'Финляндия'
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

При запуске выдается следующая ошибка:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) [http://localhost:4200/src/app/js/lib/angular.min.js]
```

ReferenceError: angular is not defined
localhost:4200:21
    at http://localhost:4200/:21:21

Не пойму почему не видит файл в локальной папке, хотя по ссылке открывается...
Как победить?

Comment: очевидно что angular.min.js по такому пути у вас на веб сервере нет, и что за :21:21?

Comment: В том то и дело что есть. Скачал на сайте, положил в папку /src/app/js/lib. Из index.html с CTRL открывается, а при запуске не видит.

Comment: если вы в браузере перейдете по указанному пути будет тоже 404?

Comment: Нет. Открывается index.html такого содержания: 

Название: {{phone.name}} . 

Цена: {{phone.price}} $

Производитель: {{phone.company.name}} ...Отрабатывает код только без angular

Comment: Пробовал подключить гиперссылкой - работает: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>. Если подключаю любой другой скрипт локально - не видит.

Comment: localhost:4200/src/app/js/lib/angular.min.js по этой ссылке открывается html?

Comment: Именно. Такое ощущение что отрабатывает только localhost:4200.

Comment: @значит проблема именно с веб сервером, какой вы используете?

Comment: установил: npm install -g @angular/cli. И запускаю: ng serve